# event.pageX and event.pageY returning a number that can't be used

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am having some trouble right now with the event.pageX and event.pageY functions.  I am trying to use them to grab the location of the mouse on a click event relative to my canvas element. I get the position relative to my canvas with these lines of code:

```
var mx = e.pageX - this.xPos;
var my = e.pageY - this.yPos;
```

`this.xPos` and `this.yPos` are obtained by using jQuery's offset function:

```
this.xPos = $("#timelines").offset().left;
this.yPos = $("#timelines").offset().top;
```

When I log either of these separately (`e.pageX/Y` or `this.x/yPos`), they give me the correct numbers. However, when I log the result of `mx` and `my` after subtracting, it says that it is not a number (NaN). I have looked around online but haven't found anything that could explain why this is happening.  I have tried explicitly casting them using `Number(event.pageX/Y)` and/or `Number(this.x/yPos)` but that didn't work.  Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Try parseFloat() around whatever base vars are non-numeric. That turns '1' (a float) into 1 (numeric)

Not familiar with jQuery, but ensure there is no 'px' at the end of the offset function?

Finally try and trigger one alert (or console.log if you must) with ALL variables that are giving you trouble to find and isolate the problem.

Comment: Actually, try replacing pageX and pageY with clientX and clientY

Comment: Checked the types of my vars with the typeof function. Both values that are used in my subtraction are numbers and clientX/Y didn't change anything

Comment: Hm. That explains why I don't have a start up. Advice: create a jsFiddle. The masters love when you do that. Leads to quicker and better solutions, especially with robust code.

Answer (score 0):

Nvm, i figured out this issue.  the value of `this` was changing in the event listener and not accessing the correct xPos/yPos